# Geometric mean of random geometric variables converging with probability to a constant

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I have the following question at hand..

> Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n$ be a sequence of iid random variables with common uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Define $$Z_n=\left(\prod_{\ i=1}^{\ n}X_i \right)^{1/n}$$ be the geometric mean of $X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n$. Show $Z_n \xrightarrow {P} c$ where $c$ is a constant.

I first found out the joint $pdf$ $f_{X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n}$.Then I substituted $X_1$ by the $Z_n$ to find out the joint $pdf$ $f_{Z_n,X_2,\cdots, X_n}$(by calculating the jacobian and applying things). It came out to be a good looking one(I dont know whether I am right or wrong..Please help) $${n\over x_2\cdots x_n}z_n^{n-1}$$

Here the problem lies. I thought I would integrate out $X_2,\cdots, X_n$ and get the $pdf $ of $Z_n$ but on integrating this it turns out $-\infty$. Where am I going wrong?

Is there some better process?

Comment: None of this is required, simply use $$\log Z_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log X_k$$ and apply the LLN to show the RHS converges to $E(\log X)=-1$ hence $$\lim Z_n=1/e.$$